# Is it possible to say: From music instruments, I like piano, drums, violin, and guitar?

Tags: word-usage

Is it possible to say: From music instruments, I like piano, drums, violin, and guitar?

Comment: I would say no, unless "music instruments" is the title of a list from which you are selecting your favorites.

Comment: Please choose a more descriptive title for your question.

Comment: What @E.Aigle said. Unless it's that unusual context (referring to a pre-existing *list*), the natural preposition would be ***Of*** or ***Among musical**  instruments, I like piano, drums, violin, and guitar* (note the adjectival form of ***music*** here, modifying the noun ***instruments***).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you are trying to say is that the musical instruments you like are piano, drums etc..

"Music" here describes the instruments. They are musical as opposed to "surgical instruments" or any other kind of instrument. "Music" is to be used as an adjective here.

In the that case you are choosing your favorites from a list called "music instruments", your proposition is fine. You are enumerating the instruments you like from the list with that title. Other wise, you'd probably be better off using:

"The musical instruments I like are piano, drums, violin and guitar.",

"Piano, drums, violin and guitar are the musical instruments I like.",

"In the category of musical instruments, I like piano, drums, violin and guitar."

This last one is really only applicable if it is said explicitly at some point that you should chose from a list or category, otherwise it's not very idiomatic.

Comment: Or maybe "**Of** musical instruments, I like..." although that's somewhat more formal than "The musical instruments I like are..."